# chrome.cookies.get not finding cookie

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying to fix this for a couple days and can't find anything online that works. When I test my chrome extension locally it works fine. When I publish it on the web store it works on my computer and only my computer. The section that is not working is reading a cookie, which should be done when the user clicks on the extension icon. When I use the web store published version on my computer it has no problem reading the cookie, but on any other computer it doesn't find the cookie, which I know is there.
Here is my getCookie function and the code when I call it, as well as my manifest.json:

Function:

```
function getCookies(domain, name, callback) {
chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
    if (cookie) {
        alert("cookie found: " + cookie.value);
        if (callback) {
            callback(cookie.value);
        }
    } else {
        alert("cookie not found");
    }

});
}
```

When it's called:

```
getCookies("http://www.mywebsite.com/", "name", function(c) {

//callback code
});
```

manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "My Extension",
"version": "1.1.7",
"permissions": [
"tabs", "cookies", "http://www.mywebsite.com/", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
],
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Do stuff.",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

Does anyone know why my extension can't find the cookie? Any ideas would be helpful, especially as to why it works on my computer when I've downloaded it from the chrome store the same as any other user might.

Thanks!

Comment: nope, i've been working on other parts of the project

Comment: Can you provide an example of a cookie that should be found, but is not?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to `chrome.cookies.getAll` instead, for some reason `chrome.cookies.get` returns `undefined` for me too :-/

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-getAll